# unable to create Istio bookinfo-gateway.yaml Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio

While running this command k

> kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml

I am getting this error

> Error from server (NotFound): error when deleting
>   "samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml": the server could
>   not find the requested resource (delete gatewaies.networking.istio.io
>   bookinfo-gateway)

Can someone please tell me how can i accept gatewaies plural ? or how to fix this error

Comment: I won't call this an error. It's just that somehow you missed to follow the prerequisites for Istio.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to latest kubectl solved the issue